# Invalid identifier on oracle inner join

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm having the error ORACLE: ORA-00904: Invalid Identifier on:

```
and l.cd_pergunta = e.cd_pergunta
```

the invalid identifier is 'e', the prefix of cd_pergunta...

When i execute this query:

```
select count(*)
  from TEACEITE e
 inner join TEREGETA re on re.cd_etapa = e.cd_etapa
                       and re.id_reg_neg = 1.00000000
 where e.obrigatorio = 1
   and not exists
 (select 1
          from GESESSAO s
         inner join GERESPOS r on r.sessao = s.sessao_resp
                              and r.resposta_log = 1
         inner join GEEPE l on l.cd_quest = s.cd_quest
                           and l.ord_perg = r.ord_pergunta
                           and l.cd_pergunta = e.cd_pergunta
         where s.cd_quest = e.cd_quest
           and s.item = e.cd_etapa
           and s.origem = 'GC'
           and s.os_nf_orc_cont = 1.00000000)
```

Any idea?

Comment: more info about the limit of one on the correlation depth can be found below (usually and eventually some way will exist to rewrite the problematic query - 
Is there some sort of nesting limit for correlated subqueries?): https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:1853075500346799932

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the alias e is not available within the nested select and hence the "invalid identifier". 
You can try to rewrite the query so that the conditions `s.cd_quest = e.cd_quest and s.item = e.cd_etapa` are part of the main select instead of the nested select.

EDIT: I tried a few scenarios and the problem is that the alias e is not available during join resolution in the nested query. Looks like you cannot refer to an outer table alias in the join condition of the inner query.

I believe that the following will work

```
  select count(*)
  from TEACEITE e
 inner join TEREGETA re on re.cd_etapa = e.cd_etapa
                       and re.id_reg_neg = 1.00000000
 where e.obrigatorio = 1
   and not exists
 (select 1
          from GESESSAO s
         inner join GERESPOS r on r.sessao = s.sessao_resp
                              and r.resposta_log = 1
         inner join GEEPE l on l.cd_quest = s.cd_quest
                           and l.ord_perg = r.ord_pergunta
         where l.cd_pergunta = e.cd_pergunta
           and s.cd_quest = e.cd_quest
           and s.item = e.cd_etapa
           and s.origem = 'GC'
           and s.os_nf_orc_cont = 1.00000000)
```

While this query may work, I am not sure if its accomplishing what you want, please ensure that your business logic is taken care of as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Raam said, you can't use the alias e inside the join of the subquery.
You can also try not to use the sql1999 syntax for joins:

```
select count(*)
  from TEACEITE e
 inner join TEREGETA re on re.cd_etapa = e.cd_etapa
                       and re.id_reg_neg = 1.00000000
 where e.obrigatorio = 1
   and not exists
 (select 1
    from GESESSAO s, GERESPOS r , GEEPE l 
   where r.sessao = s.sessao_resp
     and r.resposta_log = 1
     and l.cd_quest = s.cd_quest
     and l.ord_perg = r.ord_pergunta
     and l.cd_pergunta = e.cd_pergunta
     and s.cd_quest = e.cd_quest
     and s.item = e.cd_etapa
     and s.origem = 'GC'
     and s.os_nf_orc_cont = 1.00000000)
```