# SQL ORA-00904: invalid identifier - join issue

Tags: sql, oracle

have a problem with my query:

```
select Sources.dataset.name setName, x.element_name Commodity_Is, y.element_name Provider_Is
from meta.object_meta_v x, meta.object_meta_v y

join dw.load_set2_curve on x.object_id = dw.load_set2_curve.curve_id
join Sources.dataset on Sources.dataset.id =  dw.load_set2_curve.load_set_id
where dw.load_set2_curve.curve_id in (
    select max(curve_id) sample_curve_id from dw.load_Set2_curve
    group by load_set_id
)
and (meta.object_meta_v.attribute = 'Provider' or meta.object_meta_v.attribute = 'Commodity');
```

the error is on the line:

```
 join dw.load_set2_curve on x.object_id = dw.load_set2_curve.curve_id
```

I know why, because, according to this article 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500048/invalid-identifier-on-oracle-inner-join' - "***Looks like you cannot refer to an outer table alias in the join condition of the inner query.***" Unfortunately, I don't know how to find a workaround as I am looking for two different records (Commodity_is and Provider_is) from the same table in my query (with aliases 'x' and 'y').
Do you have any hints?

Comment: But, you don't have any subqueries (apart from that in WHERE clause) which reference *anything* so ... I think you might be wrong in identifying the problem. Query is kind of difficult to read (different users, tables, columns and almost no aliases) so - as we don't have access to your database nor know tables' description, are you sure you used **valid column names**?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about that. I know that because when I remove "y.element_name Provider_Is" column from my query, and then replace an 'x' alias with the full table name, my query executes without any errors.
So - when my query starts like this:
select Sources.dataset.name setName, meta.object_meta_v.element_name Commodity_Is
    from meta.object_meta_v    
    join dw.load_set2_curve on meta.object_meta_v.object_id = dw.load_set2_curve.curve_id

everything works fine. But when I want to search for a second column in the same table, I have to use aliases to distinguish them (x & y).

Comment: You've got the x and y aliases of meta.object_meta_v with the comma job but using the explicit join syntax for the other tables and then final line doesn't indicate whether they refer to x or y

Comment: Also (to add to what Gary said), you missed to JOIN "y" table to any other table so ... even if it worked, you'd get wrong result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not using the table aliases in the `SELECT`, `ON` and `WHERE` clauses and are trying to refer to identifiers as `schema.table.column` and, in some cases that is ambiguous and you need to use `table_alias.column`.

Additionally, you are trying to mix legacy comma joins with ANSI joins (which does work but the comma joins need to be last, not first, so its easier just to use ANSI joins all the way through):

```sql
select ds.name setName,
       x.element_name Commodity_Is,
       y.element_name Provider_Is
from   meta.object_meta_v x
       CROSS JOIN meta.object_meta_v y
       INNER JOIN dw.load_set2_curve lsc
       ON x.object_id = lsc.curve_id
       INNER JOIN Sources.dataset ds
       ON ds.id =  lsc.load_set_id
where  lsc.curve_id in (
         select max(curve_id) sample_curve_id
         from   dw.load_Set2_curve
         group by load_set_id
       )
and    (  x.attribute = 'Provider'
       or y.attribute = 'Commodity');
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE meta.object_meta_v (object_id, element_name, attribute) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', 'Provider'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B', 'Commodity' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE dw.load_set2_curve (curve_id, load_set_id) AS
SELECT 1, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 200 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE sources.dataset (id, name) AS
SELECT 100, 'DS1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 'DS2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | SETNAME | COMMODITY_IS | PROVIDER_IS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | DS1 | A | B |
> | DS1 | A | A |
> | DS2 | B | B |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=284201e3a4de743ea6099af98aecf78b)*